# Unexplained mismatch in logical subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

I am a beginner in R. I have been working with a data frame (named `df1`). `HOUSE. NO , E1, D11, DC11` are various column names in the frame. Following is the result of the logical subsetting I performed.

```
   df1
   HOUSE.NO D11 DC11 E1
75   16/215   2    2 NA
76   15/262   1    1  2
77   16/220   1    1  2
78    14/13   1    1  1
79     14/9   2    2 NA
df1$HOUSE.NO[df1$E1==1&any(!df1$D11==1,!df1$DC11==1)]
[1] NA      "14/13" NA
```

But for the "`14/13`" value, when I individually computed the value of the logical, it came out `FALSE`.

```
df1$E1[df1$HOUSE.NO=="14/13"]==1&any(df1$D11[df1$HOUSE.NO=="14/13"]!=1, df1$DC11[df1$HOUSE.NO=="14/13"]!=1)
[1] FALSE
```

I am unable to see how this came about. I also independently checked the Data frame and it made sense for it to come false. Please let me know why did this happen.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: @akrun In my case, I do not have any other place where this happened. Do you need me to give additional information from the data frame I am working on?

Comment: I don't what you to show the whole dataset.  If you show a dput of the first 6 rows or so, which will reproducible this problem, it will be easy to understand

Comment: @akrun It has 390 entries. Would a few rows of HOUSE. NO., E1, D11, DC11 columns be fine?

Comment: Just take a `sample` of the rows and that should also have the "14/13" and your problem as stated.

Comment: So, if `x <- c(1,1,1)`, you are asking us why `x[1] & any(x[2]!=1, x[3]!=1)` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot No. That is FALSE. But then why is it indexed when that is used as a condition for subsetting?

Comment: @akrun I made the problem reproducible.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I edited the data in the question to make the case simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are observing is the fact that `any` applies to a whole vector while `==` is applied to each element of the vector.

For example:

```
e1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
d11 <- c(1, 2, 2)
dc11 <- c(1, 1, 2)
house <- c("14/13", "a", "b", "c")
```

When you test this

```
house[e1==1 & any(d11!=1, dc11!=1) ]
```

all the houses are said to fulfill the condition, which is correct. But when you take a closer look at only house number 14/13, its E1 sure is equal to 1, but its D11 and DC11 are both equal to 1. That's because in the comparison focused on this house particularly, there is no other house in the `any` comparison to pass the "`any`" test.

In other words: `any(d11!=1, dc11!=1)` returns a single `TRUE` when applied to all houses because (in both our examples) there is at least on house for which D11 or DC11 is not equal to 1. When you combine this single `TRUE` with a vector of booleans (here: `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)`) with `&`, it returns the vector `c(TRUE & TRUE, TRUE & TRUE, TRUE & TRUE)`.

Now if you make the operation for house number "14/13", you will run (for the `any` part) `any(d11[house=="14/13"]!=1, dc11[house=="14/13"]!=1)` and get `FALSE`.

In conclusion, the command you want to run is

```
house[ e1[house=="14/13"]]==1 & any(d11!=1, dc11!=1) ]
```

and not

```
house[ e1[house=="14/13"]]==1 & 
    any(d11[house=="14/13"]!=1, dc11[house=="14/13"]!=1) ]
```